# Apache Solr - How to check if the parameter was entered correctly?

Tags: solr, log4j, log4j2

Due to the vulnerability in  Apache Solr affected by Apache Log4J CVE-2021-44228, one of the solutions was to edit your solr.in.sh file to include: SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true" solution.

After editing is there a way to check/test if editing was done correctly?

Comment: You should see the parameter displayed at the bottom of the initial page of your admin panel. Upgrading to 8.11.1 is recommended, if you can't - you can replace the log4j2 jars with the 2.16.0 versions manually yourself as well. There are multiple automated tests available for the exploit itself; I'm not going to link those here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Admin screen should show the setting

[image: Solr Admin UI]